# How to add UI element dynamically according to the data

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating an app that shows multiple choise Question. and my question will be different type at every time  it will contain text,image and mp3 which display either as question or as answer. like this exaples

First type of Question

[image]

Second type of question

[image]

And third type of question

[image]

So as you can see UI element place will be vary according to the data I got for question so it can more than 50. so how can i manage that?

Comment: @Wain Actually i didant try anything at time. bcoz i am confuse that how can i do that for that much different data so i am here for idea

Comment: Perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com is better for this question.

Comment: please explain your case like, from where and in which action you are getting this data.

Comment: @suraj Actually this is language learning app which will contain exercise like this to learn things. And as i said it contain lots of exercise.

Comment: I think you can try UICollection view ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to study the [Factory method design pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)